# BADSIG error with apt-get update

Tags: 14.04, mint

Whenever I use the command `sudo apt-get update` I get the following error:

```
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
```

Please help me I am very new to all this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grabbing the missing keys

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 40976EAF437D05B5
```

Rebuild software cache

```
cd /var/lib/apt
sudo mv lists lists.old
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

Hope this answer your problem :)

Comment: I've tried this but doesn't seem to help

Comment: What's the error that appears when you type those commands?

Comment: mv: cannot move ‘lists’ to ‘lists.old/lists’: Directory not empty

Comment: After you command `cd /var/lib/apt`, enter command `sudo su`, then follow with the command above without `sudo`.